# Defining a return-transition between page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am using jQueryMobile's `$.mobile.changePage(...)` method to switch to a different page within my project.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#foo", {
 transition:"slide"
});
```

When I run that method, the transition works perfectly but when I hit the browser's return button I see no reverse transition.

I played around with some of the parameters described in http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html but had no luck.

**Especially setting `reverse:true` just reversed the transition when moving forward to the target page but there is still no transition when I hit the back button.**

---

**Update:** It seems like seeing data-rel="back" does the trick for "orginary links" defined via the `<a>`-tag **BUT** what I need is the JavaScript equivalent when calling the `$.mobile.changePage()` function.

Comment: What browser do you use for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

One of our developers turned off all return transitions globally, so no wonder that it didn't work.

This is what he used. Removing that line did the trick.

```
$.mobile.changePage.defaults.transition = "none";
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page, http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/mDTK2/show/light/
Works fine with me.

Click (on page 1) shows transition from Left to right, & Back button (on page 2) shows transition from right to left.

Source:  http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/mDTK2/
If it is not working fine, than please share your browse and other details.
If example is working fine, but not your code, make a jsfiddle highlighting your problem, so I can check and update code/answer.

Comment: Yes, creating a plain jQM Project works fine. Looks like this behavior only appears in my app. Unfortunately the source code is confidential. What would be a good practice to debug this?

Comment: @valmar You should enable the debug console for Safari: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/07/enable-safari-debug-console-ios/

Answer (score 2):

For the links you want to have the reverse transition on you can use `data-direction="reverse"` with `data-rel="back"`

Example:

```
<div data-role="page" >
    <div data-role="header"><h3> Header </h3> </div>
    <div data-role="content" >    
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header"><h3> Header </h3> </div>
    <div data-role="content" >    
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" >Back</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/GEDcF/

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/data-attributes.html

UPDATE

From your comment

```
"Yeah, but how do I do that with the JavaScript function $.mobile.changePage()?"
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html

Quote:

```
Properties:
     reverse (boolean,  default:    false) Decides what direction the transition will run when showing the page.
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I do that with the JavaScript function `$.mobile.changePage()`?

Comment: Nope, that's wrong. As I already stated in my original question, using `reverse=true` will just tell jQM to use the back-transition when moving forward from one page to another. It won't affect the transition when going back to a previous page.